# TypeGraphQL Field Resolver returns undefined

Tags: mongoose, graphql, typegraphql, typegoose

I have built my back-end with Typegoose+TypeGraphQL. I have an ObjectType that looks like this:

[image]

I want workoutAmount to pretty much just return the length of workouts array. The array always exists, so it's either empty or has some objects in it. The problem I am having is that `this.workouts` returns `undefined`. I have coded this pretty much as the example is on TypeGraphQL docs for Field Resolvers, but I can't seem to get this to work.

Here is what is getting printed if I `console.log(this)` before returning. The workouts array exists, but I can't access it.

[image]

Comment: This looks like what `class-transformer` would output, is it used somewhere in the pipeline, also is your function `workoutAmount` called on a mongoose model or some class instance or somewhere else?

Comment: `workoutAmount` should show the length of the `workouts` array in the GraphQL mutation result.